# Firebase Cloud Firestore get auto-id of newly created document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a user with the following code, however since the Document ID of the user is randomly generated, I would like to store the DocumentReference in a variable after it has been created.  How could I do this?

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

// Create a new user with a first, middle, and last name
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("username", "username");
user.put("first", "Firstname");
user.put("last", "Lastname");
user.put("born", 1990);

// Add a new document with a generated ID
db.collection("users")
        .add(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());

            }

        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you find a way to store that.. Please tell me how to do that. I want to get that auto generated Id and use it to delete that document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `add()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, you should expect to do *anything* with the resulting DocumentReference via the success listener you provided.  Attempting to assign something to a local variable will not likely be helpful, because the rest of the code your method that invoked add() will almost certainly be complete by the time the callback is invoked.

If you want a random document ID immediately, before the document is actually created, use `document()` with no parameters instead of `add()`.  This will get you a DocumentReference for a random document not yet created, which already had an ID assigned.  Then you can `set()` that whenever you're ready.

Comment: I need to get the id and pass it to another activity in android. But id shows null. can u say the solution for that issue

Answer (score 3):

you can create a new document and save its id, then set the data on that id that will work the same as you asked for.try the following code.

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
String id = db.collection("users").document().getId();
db.collection("users").document(id).set(user)
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
       //your success code here
       }})
  .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

       }});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get the **document id** from **onSuccess** and save it into a **variable** `id` like this

```
id = documentReference.getId()
```