# Can't get Auto-ID Document in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Excuse me,
I'm working on my code about making a Document Firestore that could be delete, this is how my Firestore Database looks like :
[Firestore Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBXZU.jpg)

I'd like to delete the Auto-ID Document after the Collection "X-MIPA.6". So, I followed the previous solution about "[Firebase Cloud Firestore get auto-id of newly created document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492527/firebase-cloud-firestore-get-auto-id-of-newly-created-document?rq=1)", so here is my code looks like :
[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGloV.jpg)

But, when I tested, my app force closed and show me this Error :
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMlzV.jpg)

How is it possible? How can I fix it?
I want to delete the Document based on the Auto-ID Document on my Firestore Database.
Thanks!

Comment: Please replace the link to  a pictures of code and error, with the actual code as text. Textual content should be included as text, to allow people to immediately see what you're doing, to make it accessible through search engines, and to make it easier to use the text to reproduce the problem or answer your question.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EbZFT1PH
This is my code

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?